# What do you call a matrix where the rows sum to zero and the columns sum to zero?

Tags: matrices, terminology

What do you call a matrix where the rows sum to zero and the columns sum to zero?

Or is there no standard name for this type of matrix?

Comment: With a quick google search, it seems that the phrase "matrix with a zero (or more generally: prescribed/constant) row/column sum" has no common abbreviation.

Comment: Seems this was already asked [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/617332/question-about-matrices-whose-row-and-column-sums-are-zero).

Comment: The answer linked doesn't provide any kind of name for these matrices; this question should not be closed as a duplicate since it has not already been answered.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what "context or other details" would make this question any clearer.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/a/36668/41862 Seems they are called tactical configurations in certain contexts.

Comment: If it's a square matrix it would be a special case of a "Magic Square"